# Classic ASP SQL string

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I need to pass generated sql string and query database and need to get data  out of it.

```
      dim sql,spack
  spack="test"
  sql="select * from dbo.packageName A where a.custname=" & spack 

  set rs = getRs(sql)
```

This code statement return error. Could you please someone explain me how to pass parameter like above code segment(parameter spack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Varial should be inclosed in single quotes

```
 sql="select * from dbo.packageName A where a.custname='" & spack & "'"
```